# UIAlertView in swift / Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question concerning a `UIAlertview` in swift. I have an alert view that allows the user to choose between two options "Teacher" and "Student" and takes the user to a new screen depending on which button is clicked. It's working fine the only problem is I have a back button on each of the new screens which takes the user back to the previous screen in case they clicked the wrong button. Here is where the problem occurs. If the user clicks the button that triggers the `alertview` after `naviagting` back to the page, the `alertivew` remembers which button the user clicked last time and executes based off of that. Sorry if that is confusing, I want them to be able to choose between the options every time and have the `alertview` not execute based off of their previous choice. Sorry if that was confusing, all help is appreciated greatly.

Here is my code currently

@IBAction func needToRegisterClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please choose", message: "Teacher or Student?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Teacher", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in

        print("Teacher Chosen")



        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Access Code", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad }



        ac.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            let answer = ac.textFields![0] as! UITextField
            if answer.text == "3280464" {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("School Register", sender: nil)

            } else {

                let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "Incorrect access code", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

                alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: nil))


            }
            // do something interesting with "answer" here
        }

        ac.addAction(submitAction)

        self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)






    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Student", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in

        print("Student Chosen")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Student", sender: nil)


    }))
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)





}
```

Edit: How exactly would I go about instantiating a new alertView everytime the button is pressed? Sorry if that is a dumb thing to ask, I am extremely new to the entire thing.

Edit: I tried all of the suggested options with no luck but I just now was able to figure it out on my own. All I needed to do was remove self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) from the end. Thanks to everyone who responded, I sincerely appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Try instantiating a new alert view each time the button is pressed instead of using the same one

Comment: Can you post your code please

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is back to the first ViewController if the user press an incorrect action in the alert controller, so what i did is:
- I added the 'student' button with the same code that the teachers's button
- I created a var that stores a Boolean value, if true is a teacher, else, is a student, when you choose the you are a teacher, the var is stored with a true value, else, if student button is pressed, it stores false, and then go to the next ViewController
- In the second ViewController i created a button(back)

`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToFirst", sender: self)`

> FirstViewController

```
import UIKit
```

var isTeacher: Bool!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func needToRegisterClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please choose", message: "Teacher or Student?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //Button teacher

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Teacher", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in

        print("Teacher Chosen")

        isTeacher = true

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Access Code", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad }



        ac.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            let answer = ac.textFields![0] as! UITextField
            if answer.text == "3280464" {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("School Register", sender: self)

            } else {

                let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "Incorrect access code", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

                alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: nil))


            }
            // do something interesting with "answer" here
        }

        ac.addAction(submitAction)

        self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        //Ends Button Teacher

        )


    )

    //Button Student

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Student", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in

        print("Student Chosen")

        isTeacher = false

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Access Code", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad }



        ac.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            let answer = ac.textFields![0] as! UITextField
            if answer.text == "3280464" {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("School Register", sender: self)

            } else {

                let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "Incorrect access code", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

                alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: nil))


            }
            // do something interesting with "answer" here
        }

        ac.addAction(submitAction)

        self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


        )


    )

    //Ends Button Student

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

> SecondViewController

```
import UIKit
```

class Logged: ViewController {

```
@IBAction func Back(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToFirst", sender: self)

}

@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(isTeacher == true){

        navBar.topItem?.title = "Teacher Area"

    }else{

        navBar.topItem?.title = "Student Area"

    }



}
```

}

Wish helped you